# android "insta apps" updating without permission

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, application-autoupdate

Happened to open my android Marshmallow based screen on my unrooted phone.  Saw a message that "insta apps" was updating.  Download completed before I could stop it and update history does not show this package as being updated.
I have:

1. verified that there is no package installed in the settings->apps list with insta apps in it's name.
2. verified that install from 3rd party source is turned off in my settings->security options
3. made sure that my play store settings for auto-update apps is set to do not auto-update apps.
4. did an adb backup and had a look at the package list and did not find any apps with insta in their package name.

I did download a audio recorder application from the play store which kept flashing dodgy messages.  Maybe it installed something else?

Anyway to track down what this is?  My phone is not rooted but I do have dev studio access to it.  Maybe it's time to put the phone in the wood chiper and never use the playstore again?

Comment: There's a [developer by that name](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=INSTA+APPS) if that's some pointer. My first thought was that new sort of apps you don't install at all, see e.g. [here](http://techmetrick.com/how-to-search-and-use-android-instant-apps/) – which would explain why you cannot find it in installed apps. Could that be?

Comment: thanks for the pointer.  Aware of the instant apps packages but this was distinctly "insta apps" which appears to be a highly questionable vendor.  The app seems to be targeting my android pay information.